# Are there any ancient temples dedicated to Radha devi in the South Indian states?

Tags: krishna, temple, radha

Many temples dedicated to Radhika devi, beloved of Krishna, are found in Northern India. Specially in Braj mandala region of Uttar Pradesh. These temples have either local folklore significance or based on puranas and other holy scriptures.

Are there similar temples dedicated to Radha as standalone deity or in couple with Krishna in the non-Northern Indian regions, especially South India?